# How to remove OG meta tags value from URL response

Tags: javascript, html, telegram-bot, telegraf

I work with Telegram API using npm package [Telegraf](https://telegraf.js.org)

When I reply message to user in HTML format with custom link:

```
ctx.replyWithHTML(`<a href="https://babolo.tj/jobs/kreditnyj-ekspert-26064">Credit Expert</a>`)
```

Then return me page OG meta tag values. I need only to link in my case and not need to other data something like: title, page description or meta tag values e.t.c

I tried do it using javascript but link not work:

```
ctx.replyWithHTML(`<a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='https://babolo.tj/jobs/kreditnyj-ekspert-26064'">Credit Expert</a>`)
```

In this case link displayed as plain text instead of correct URL

How I can send to user correct link without link response title, OG meta tags?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [disable_web_page_preview](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) parameter of sendMessage.

```js
ctx.replyWithHTML(`<a href="https://babolo.tj/jobs/kreditnyj-ekspert-26064">Credit Expert</a>`, {disable_web_page_preview: true})
```